# Getting cluster detail of Windows

Tags: powershell

Is there any other way to get Windows cluster details like cluster & machine info using PowerShell command?
I tried to use `Get-Cluster` command but it's not working throwing an error.

```
get-cluster : The term 'get-cluster' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-cluster
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-cluster:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you imported the module ?
Import-Module FailoverClusters

Comment: Unless you have a programming question, this would be better on-topic at ServerFault.

Comment: What is your Windows version? What is your PowerShell version? Did you already install the respective PowerShell module from the RSAT?

Comment: Windows version is 2012 R2 std, and PS is 4

Comment: `Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell`, then try again.

Comment: How to do it , just copy your above command and run it in powershell ?

Comment: even "Add-WindowsFeature: does not work

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"?